# Check one column with strings and get sum of values from second column (pythonic way)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given this data frame:

```
d = {'SITE':['AB', 'ON', 'YO', 'YO', 'AB'],
 'MARK':['ss', 'ss', 'tt', 'ss', 'tt'], 
 'SIZE': [4, 5, 2, 3, 4]} 

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

To get the `column['SIZE']` sum for only the `column['SITE'] == 'AB'` one can slice
the AB containing only df using `AB_df = ex_df[ex_df.SITE == 'AB']` and then `AB_df.SIZE.sum()`, which is `8`.

However, given a similar data frame with 10,000+ rows and 12 columns, and over 40 unique `column['SITE']` strings.

Q1: How can you get the `SIZE` sum for each `SITE` without having to write 40 lines of the same code as above (changing the `SITE` name).

Q2: How can you add more conditions, such as check that if a condition matches two columns, the `SITE & MARK`, and then get the `SIZE` sum, without having to again write 40 lines of repetitive code.

I'd like to save the result either in a list containing the sums or dictionary with the site and sum `{AB:8, ON:5, ...}` or even a new data frame with that information.

I've tried to use a `list` of the `40 unique sites` to iterate through the data frame column, but without success given length differences, etc.

I'm looking to make this pythonic ideally. Thanks!

Comment: Try `df.groupby('SITE')['SIZE'].sum().to_dict()`  `df.groupby(['SITE','MARK'])['SIZE'].sum().to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 Can be accomplished with a groupby in Pandas:

```py
grouped_df = ex_df.groupby('SITE').agg({'SIZE': 'sum'}
```

To accomplish Q2, you likely need to implement a custom function to pass to the `.agg` call, something like:

```py
def my_filter(df: pd.Dataframe):
    # Filters can be modified as needed
    return df[df['SITE'].startswith('A') & df['MARK'] == 'tt']['SIZE'].sum()

grouped_df = ex_df.groupby('SITE').agg(my_filter)
```

However, if your goal for Q2 is simply to group the rows by SITE *AND* MARK, you can do:

```py
grouped_df = ex_df.groupby(['SITE', 'MARK']).agg({'SIZE': 'sum'})
```

Then you don't have to worry about writing a custom filtering function.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should give you a sum of each SITE for each row:

```
ex_df['Max'] = ex_df.groupby(['SITE'])['SIZE'].transform(sum)
```

If not please clarify further for further assistance.